# Cost-efficient way of returning n-th object of parameter pack at runtime

Tags: c++, c++17, runtime, variadic-templates, parameter-pack

Here's a problem that I'm scratching my head over: I want to return the n-th object of a variadic template parameter pack whereas the index is known only at runtime.

I could just put every parameter in a tuple and then access the tuple, however, AFAIK this comes with the additional cost of initializing the tuple with every element of the argument list and even if its just moving the objects into the tuple that's still cost that I don't really feel like paying as it isn't aligned with what I actually want to do. So I feel there must be a better way. Maybe there's a way of preselecting the argument at compile time somehow?

My intention in code:

```
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>


volatile int index = 2;

template <typename... Ts>
std::variant<Ts...> foo(Ts&&... args) {
    return { /* args[index] */ };
}

int main()
{
    foo(2, "hello", 3.4);
}
```

Any ideas are welcome! :)

Comment: Tuple of references perhaps?

Comment: What if instead of passing the parameter pack to a function you use it to directly initialise the tuple?

Comment: As far as I know, what you're attempting is impossible. You're trying to have the cake and eat it too. Parameter packs are operated upon at compile time. Indexed access must also follow this rule.

Comment: I think the only way to solve that is to recursively iterate over the pack, chopping of elements at the start till you hit the right element. It's tail recursive so it should be equivalent to a `while` loop over the pack. You could provide functions to skip ahead 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ... elements to get it down to `O(log n)`.

Comment: @KrzysiekKarbowiak: I don't think it should be impossible. The instantiated function would AFAIK reserve at least n times the pointer size on the stack for every argument (in case reference is passed) it's basically contiguous memory and I should be able to access it. In case values are copied the stack will grow by n elements of the respespective size. The compiler should be able to generate a symbol for each variable one way or the other. The question is how?

Comment: Something along [these lines](https://godbolt.org/z/KaP65oxYY), based on the idea by @GoswinvonBrederlow